# All product displaying placeholder image instead of uploaded images

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, placeholder

I try to re save, reindex,update attribute, clear cache, images are checked in backend. 777 permission is given to media folder. i have disabled all extensions which were over-riding media.phtml but still it showing placeholder even in product listing page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a lot of googling I found solution [here](http://www.sangaytenzin.com/magento-1-8-bug-memory-limit-has-been-reached/)

> There is a file called Gd2.php in the folder lib/Varien/Image/Adapter
>
> There is a function called _convertToByte() which checks for php_memory limit. The function checks whether the size is given in M or KB and converts to bytes accordingly. The bug is, it does not check if the size is given in GB. So if you are going through above same problems, apparently your server has php_memory limit given in GB.
>
> ```
> protected function _convertToByte($memoryValue)
> {
>     if (stripos($memoryValue, 'M') !== false) {
>       return (int)$memoryValue * 1024 * 1024;
>     }
>     elseif (stripos($memoryValue, 'KB') !== false) {
>       return (int)$memoryValue * 1024;
>     }
>  
>     return (int)$memoryValue;
> }
> ```

Solution is to either set the memory limit to a value in megabytes (i.e. 2048M instead of 2G) or if it's not possible, hack this file to make it work with gigabyte values.